# Permission errors when installing software via apt or dpkg

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, deb, dpkg

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 and lately I am having lots of troubles when it comes to installing new software using `apt` or `dpkg`. The error I am getting is always the same:

```
sudo dpkg -i code_1.11.2-1492070517_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 301548 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack code_1.11.2-1492070517_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking code (1.11.2-1492070517) over (1.11.2-1492070517) ...
dpkg: error processing archive code_1.11.2-1492070517_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to open '/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/electron-browser/workbench.main.nls.de.js.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+17.04.20170406-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 code_1.11.2-1492070517_amd64.deb
```

This time I was trying to install Visual Studio Code with `dpkg` using the official `deb` file. I fixed it by using `dpkg`'s flag `--force-all`, which allowed me to install the package successfully.

However, I would like to know what this error means, why I am getting it so often and how to prevent it. Today I have had this error 3 times in a row when trying to install 3 different packages!

Comment: What's the output of dpkg --audit

Comment: I get no output from that, both with `sudo` and without `sudo`. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: May your OS is not x64 since this line: `error processing archive code_1.11.2-1492070517_amd64.deb`

Comment: @k-five `uname -a` outputs `Linux zorrigato 4.10.0-20-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:22:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, so I think I am running a x64 OS. Thanks!

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem on ubuntu 17.10. It seems that running the same command multiple times will eventually get the package installed without error. Each time dpkg is run in this case, a different file is shown.